# autoLink text color

Tags: colors, appcelerator, autolink

is it even possible to change the color of an "autoLink"ed label ?

Alloy :

```
<Label autoLink="Ti.UI.AUTOLINK_EMAIL_ADDRESSES" color="#fff" text="blabla email@fai.com">
```

The label is white but the email is kind of blue.

I tried everything (except "theme" stuff which I don't really know - I suppose solution may be there), and found no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can use the `tintColor` property to change the color of the link.  This may or may not work on Android though.

Comment: Thanks, but indeed as the doc says (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label-property-tintColor) it is only for IOS, I tried on android but no result :)
(And my app is not on iOS yet).

Comment: @John it would be good to create a feature request for this at [Appcelerator's JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org)